# Does Google Tag Manager ignore META tags CSS selectors?

Tags: google-tag-manager

First we had a variable set to look at: meta[property='gtm'] value input was "content"

GTM Preview retunrs NULL for that variable/value

So then we tried

meta id="gtm-tagmanger" content="foo"

and setup a css selector to look ID of "gtm-tagmager", value in content

Then trigger was set to use Variable when equals "foo"

Still not firing.

I am beginning to believe - GTM does *NOT* read meta properties. Can anyone confirm or deny this?

Comment: It is really hard so say if you have typos or if your examples are wrong. GTM reads meta tags and you can access them via a css selector with the property attribute (I just tested this).  Can you add a screenshot of your setup ?

Comment: It was the strangest thing. No typos, nothing changed, all the sudden GTM started reading the variables / values correctly (after 6 hr period)

Very may well have been a bug @ google with some updates.

Comment: Well your question misspelled "property" (was missing the "y" in your first line), that's why I asked for typos. Glad to hear it works now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to get meta properties by using the "DOM Element" variable type:
[image]

Comment: Does not exactly answer the question since that was about meta tags with a content attribute (of which there may be several and the CSS selector would only return the first). So like the OP tried the selector would need to be meta[property='gtm'] (only the question misspelled "property"). Maybe you could update the screenshot to make it match the question (just so nobody gets confused) ?

Comment: @EikePierstorff, thanks for the feedback, updated the image!

Answer (score 1):

Correct method to get this value into the VARIABLE is to configure the DOM Element , CSS Selector as such:

It was this way - it seems google had a bug. Uploading a photo for clarity

This will look for the

`<meta property="gtm" content="foo" />`

tag, and then the variable for that will have the "foo" value

[image]